# Insert the pressed item into an array in react-native

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native

I have a list of tag objects in array (**tagList**), which I am fetching from the server and storing into the state. After a succesfull fetch I am mapping each item inside a `ScrollView`.

```
export default class RegisterTags extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            tagList: [],
            selectedTags: [],
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {
        api.getTagsOnRegister()
            .then((res) => {
                this.setState({
                    tagList: res
                })
            })
    }

    insertTag = (tag) =>{
        this.setState({
            selectedTags: this.state.selectedTags.push(tag)
        })
    }


    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={styles.ScrollViewContainer}>
                    {this.state.tagList.map((tag) => {
                        return(
                            <View style={styles.tagStyle} key={tag.id} onPress={this.insertTag(tag)}>
                                <Text style={styles.tagText}>{tag.name}</Text>
                            </View>
                        )
                    })}
                </ScrollView>
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is, when I press on any of the tag, I would like to add that object into the selectedTags array. But I am getting error:

> Warning: setState(...): Cannot update during an existing state transition (such as within `render` or another component's constructor). Render methods should be a pure function of props and state; constructor side-effects are an anti-pattern, but can be moved to `componentWillMount`.
>
> Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
> _this.state.selectedTags.push is not a function
> TypeError: _this.state.selectedTags.push is not a function

How can I add the pressed tag item into the **selectedTags** array?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
onPress={this.insertTag(tag)}
```

**Issue**: in your `render` function  you are directly calling a function that changes state. `Render` function should never call any function that updates state.

So how to call `onPress`?

Ans: as written below

```
onPress = {() => {this.insertTag(tag) }}
```

**Will code work now?**
Answer is no.

You have to put your views inside `TouchableHighlight` and move `onPress` method from `View` to `TouchableHighlight`. 
Then hopefully your code works. I am assuming everything is setup property.

**~~~~~~EDIT 1~~~~~~~~**

**What't the difference between** `onPress={this.insertTag(tag)}` **and** `onPress = {() => {this.insertTag(tag) }}`

**Every thing inside curly braces are expressions in react jsx**. Now `onPress={this.insertTag(tag)}`  evaluates the expression inside curly braces and assign it to onPress property, and in your case `this.insertTag` happens to update state.

While `onPress = {() => {this.insertTag(tag) }}` , on evaluating curly braces returns a function, but doesn't call that function. And when onPress event is triggered than that function is called.

Google "Arrow Function" for more.

Comment: Wow.. I never realized this much. Its working, thank you sir. Could you please help me understand a little more on this concept. By calling a function like this `onPress={this.insertTag(tag)}` will automatically call the function on `render`, and calling a function like this `onPress => {() = {this.insertTag(tag) }}` will only call the function on press?

Comment: Hello, I have edited answer to explain arrow functions